# XPath evaluation failing

Tags: xpath

What would be the Xpath code required to get all of the nodes under Price?

So far I have tried `AMUpdate/AMMesageType/amprice/Price`, which is failing.

```
<AMUpdate>
    <AMMessageType>AMPRICES</AMMessageType>
    <amprice:AMPrices xmlns:amprice="http://www/am.com/am/dto/price">
        <Price>
            <Currency>GBP</Currency>
            <Country>LU</Country>
            <BusinessLine>AMSL</BusinessLine>
        </Price>
    </amprice:AMPrices>
</AMUpdate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below Xpath,

```
/AMUpdate/amprice:AMPrices/Price/*
```

You XML have a closing tag missing. Please find the updated XML,

```html
<AMUpdate>
  <AMMessageType>AMPRICES</AMMessageType>
  <amprice:AMPrices xmlns:amprice="http://www/am.com/am/dto/price">
    <Price>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Country>LU</Country>
      <BusinessLine>AMSL</BusinessLine>
    </Price>
    </amprice:AMPrices>
</AMUpdate>
```

You can try testing XPath [here](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)

Comment: Nothing is returned: http://www.xpathtester.com/colored/134b06bf66abb25bf4f2689a248baeae

Comment: You XML have a missing close tag. I have updated the answer with correct XML and link where you can test the XPath I have given. it is working for me.